# Nvidia Quadro 4000 at VERY high idle temperature

Tags: graphics-card, temperature

My Nvidia Quadro 4000 is running at ~70°C (idle, GPU have 0,1% load) in a very cold environment (server room with air conditioning). Is that normal? How can I fix this? The card is not covered by warranty anymore.
Thanks.

Comment: No; it's not normal; verify it's fan is working

Comment: All the fan case and the fan of the card itself are working properly.

Comment: Have you tried to apply some load to that card and see if it heats up more when it is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Open up the card and replace the thermal compound, and use canned air to dust off the heat sink to get rid of the dust blocking the opening near the fan. Considering how expensive the card is a better heat sink might be a good investment.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia Quadro 4000 is ~150W graphics card.

I guess you have Maximum Performance set in Nvidia Control Panel. If thats true - ~70°C is normal.

You can switch it to Adaptive (Nvidia help: [link](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3130/~/setting-power-management-mode-from-adaptive-to-maximum-performance)). GPU and memory will slow down only when there is no load.

Maximum Performance mode is not good idea if you have your workstation turned on 24/7. It reduces fan bearings lifetime.

You should worry when card shutdowns due to overheating.

Answer (score 0):

Your desktop screen configuration could play into the high temperature. I had one screen in landscape and the other in portrait with slightly different resolutions. This caused my resting temp to be about 85C. Once I set them both to the same settings my temp dropped 25 degrees to a resting 60C.

It's a bit counter-intuitive that having dual monitors with one set a little different would cause such a load on the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

We have this graphics card at work running two monitors with different resolutions. Idle temperatures were around 85-90°C with the case open. We changed the resolution to the same resolution and it really worked - the temperatures went down very quickly.

Comment: What should OP do? What do suggest?

Answer (score 0):

These cards are getting old now, and may need some TLC to keep running at a sensible idle temperature.

My card was idling at 85c and cutting out under load.

To access the heat sink and chip, unscrew the 4 large sprung Philips screws on the back.

My card had developed a felted mass of dust preventing airflow through the cooling fins. And the thermal paste had dried and wasn't functional.

After cleaning the fins and replacing the paste the idle temperature has dropped to 55c, and I'll hopefully get a few more years of use from the card.